# Need @icloud.com address associated with my Apple ID

Tags: icloud, apple-id

I had to replace my iPhone and I can log into my Apple ID using my Gmail account. But some features on the iPhone are requiring my @icloud.com login.

How do you recover that specific account? I have been through Apple support to recover my Apple ID account, to at least restore my contacts and other settings. I want to pair my apple watch to my current iPhone, and it is requiring that i insert my @icloud.com ID to verify the Apple Watch.

Comment: log in to iCloud using your Apple ID, there in your profile you will find your email

Comment: Two weeks ago I bought an Apple watch and successfully paired it to my iPhone using an Apple ID that wasn't an icloud.com account. My domain is @telus.net and I've been using it for many years with my Apple devices without a problem.  So if you have an existing Apple ID that uses gmail.com you should be able to use it to pair your watch.  My reading of their documentation is the only time you're required to use an icloud.com ID is if you're changing from one email account to another and your existing account is an icloud.com ID.

Answer (score 1):

Use your Apple ID (Gmail) to log into [Manage Your Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com/) website.

Now, once you have successfully logged in, you should be able to see your @icloud.com ID under **Contactable At** heading within **Account** section.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you are able to log into your Apple ID, use that ID to log into [appleid.apple.com](https://appleid.apple.com/)

[image]

From there you can see your iCloud credentials.